# How do I set relationships between tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I've designed and created a decently-sized database with lots of relationships, but I've got no idea how to define the relationships in MySQL.

For instance I want my `users` table to have a 1 to 1 relationship with the `addresses` table, but to have a many to 1 relationship with my `user_products` table.

How do I go about setting up these relationships?

Comment: Look up *Foreign Key Relations*

Comment: Also unique key restraints

Comment: @juergend I've set up my foreign and primary keys for all of my tables, I'm just unsure how to set relationships between tables

Comment: If you defined a foreign key then this is already the relation definition.

Comment: Just as an aside, make sure the Engine you use supports foreign keys. MyISAM for example, does not, whilst InnoDB does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have defined a foreign key like

```
CREATE TABLE user_products 
(
... FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`)
    REFERENCES users (id) ...
```

then this is already the definition of a relation. It tells the DB that in `user_id` of table `user_products` there can only be ids from the column `id` of table `users`.

Comment: That's interesting, how does it know which will be a 1-many or 1-1 relation?

Comment: Sorry, just figured out I need to do the further definition in the cake console itself. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The example above is a 1-m relation. If you want 1-1 then you can add a unique key on the foreign key. That makes sure the user_id is only once in the table.